# The <Link></Link> react-tag seems to be preventing my app from rendering

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to construct/replicate an e-commerce website using React. When trying to launch the dev server, I noticed that I wasn't getting anything rendered on my screen. Using the React Dev tools extension confirmed as much. From past experiences, adding the links to the App.js file would probably solve this, however, I'd rather have the links in the Header component.
I am trying to link the image such that when I click on the image, it will render the  component without refreshing. I believe I have followed all the required steps as per the react-router-dom documentation, but I can't get the site to work if I include the  tag.

I commented out a few sections as I initially thought I had implemented the ContextAPI incorrectly. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's a snippet of my App.js file

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Header, Home } from './components'

import './App.css'

function App() {
    return (
        <div className='app'>
            <Header />
            <Router>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Here's the Home.jsx file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Product } from '..'

import { heroLanding, products } from '../../constants'

import './Home.css'

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div className='home'>
            <img src={heroLanding} alt='Landing Page' className='home__image' />

            <div className='home__row'>
                {products.map(
                    (product, index) =>
                        index < 2 && (
                            <Product
                                key={product.id}
                                title={product.title}
                                rating={product.rating}
                                price={product.price}
                                image={product.image}
                            />
                        )
                )}
            </div>
            <div className='home__row'>
                {products.map((product, index) =>
                    (index > 1) & (index < 5) ? (
                        <Product
                            key={product.id}
                            title={product.title}
                            rating={product.rating}
                            price={product.price}
                            image={product.image}
                        />
                    ) : null
                )}
            </div>
            <div className='home__row'>
                {products.map((product, index) =>
                    index > 4 ? (
                        <Product
                            key={product.id}
                            title={product.title}
                            rating={product.rating}
                            price={product.price}
                            image={product.image}
                        />
                    ) : null
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Here's the Header.jsx file:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BsCart4 as BasketIcon, BsSearch as Search } from 'react-icons/bs'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

import { logo } from '../../constants'
//import { useStateValue } from '../../contextAPI/StateProvider'

import './Header.css'

const Header = () => {
    // const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue()

    return (
        <div className='header'>
            <Link to='/'>
                <img src={logo} alt='Amazon Logo' className='header__logo' />
            </Link>

            <div className='header__search'>
                <input
                    className='header__search-input'
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='Search ...'
                />
                <span className='header__searchIcon'>
                    <Search className='header__searchIcon-icon' />
                </span>
            </div>

            <div className='header__nav'>
                <div className='header__option'>
                    <span className='header__option-lineOne'>Hello User</span>
                    <span className='header__option-lineTwoe'>Sign In</span>
                </div>
                <div className='header__option'>
                    <span className='header__option-lineOne'>Returns</span>
                    <span className='header__option-lineTwoe'>&amp; Orders</span>
                </div>
                <div className='header__option'>
                    <span className='header__option-lineOne'>Your</span>
                    <span className='header__option-lineTwo'>Prime</span>
                </div>
                <div className='header__option-basket'>
                    <BasketIcon />
                    <span className='header__option-lineTwo header__basketCount'>0</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header
```

Comment: I essentially transferred the content of the App.js file into the header, such that the App.js file only has the header component in it. The links and Routes are now in the Header.jsx file. Is that the correct way to do things? If I remember correctly, isn't the Router meant to be used only in high-level elements i.e. the App.js file?

Answer (score 1):

You should put **Router** at the beginning of the return statement in **App.js**.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Header, Home } from './components'

import './App.css'

function App() {
    return (
     <Router>
        <div className='app'>
            <Header />
            
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
                </Routes>
            
        </div>
     </Router>
    )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Wasn't the Switch tag replaced with Routes in v6 of react-router-dom? Or rather, the Routes tag was introduced as a more powerful version of Switch?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about that. Its Routes in v6. it's my mistake, I was going through v5 doc.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am quite frustrated with myself that it was such a fundamental mistake that I had overlooked. 

On your recommendations for wrapping the <App/> in my index.js file, when I do so I get an error - "Uncaught Error: You cannot render a <Router> inside another <Router>. You should never have more than one in your app." I understand the error, so if you don't mind clarifying how to go about doing what you have suggested I would appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The issue with the code is that the header and links are rendered ***outside*** the router handling the routes. This means it's [`Router`] not aware of any external navigation actions above it in the React tree.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <Header />
      <Router> // <-- routing context isn't aware of external actions
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Since you are using `react-router-dom@6` you should certainly have some errors in the console warning you that the `Link` components have been rendered outside any routing context and to move them into one.

## Solution

The `Header` component (*and links*) need to be moved ***into*** a router so they receive a proper routing context. You need only one router per app also, so go through your code and remove any extraneous routers you may have. This is so all RRD components use the same single routing context.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className='app'>
      <Router>
        <Header /> // <-- move inside routing context
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  )
}
```

In most cases you will want to push the `Router` as high as possible in your application's ReactTree. It's common to wrap `App` in the index.js file so anything `App` is rendering will have the proper routing context available to it.

Example:

```
...
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
...

ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    .... other context wrappers ....
      <Router>
        <App />
      </Router>
    .... other context wrappers ....
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```